# WHERE OR query with WHERE AND with PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Tags: php, mysql, php-mysqlidb

I am using [MysqlDb Class](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php) in my Project.

```
$fromquery = $jdb->where("ac_ag_Id",1)->orWhere("ac_ag_Id",2)->orWhere("ac_ag_Id",4)->orWhere("ac_ag_Id",17)->where("c_Id",$cc_Id)->get("tbl_accounts")
```

This is my current query and the result is

```
SELECT  * FROM tbl_accounts WHERE  ac_ag_Id = '1'  OR ac_ag_Id = '2'  OR ac_ag_Id = '4'  OR ac_ag_Id = '17'  AND c_Id = '2'
```

Here, `c_Id` must be `2`, but I am getting result of `c_Id` of `1` also. So I added a bracket which looks like this and I get the currect result

```
SELECT  * FROM tbl_accounts WHERE  (ac_ag_Id = '1'  OR ac_ag_Id = '2'  OR ac_ag_Id = '4'  OR ac_ag_Id = '17')  AND c_Id = '2'
```

How to get this result form that class like adding function `andWhere` or something?

Comment: Use c_Id  in beginning of OR Condition.  SELECT  * FROM tbl_accounts WHERE c_Id = '2'  AND (ac_ag_Id = '1'  OR ac_ag_Id = '2'  OR ac_ag_Id = '4'  OR ac_ag_Id = '17')

Comment: $fromquery = $jdb->where("c_Id",$cc_Id)->where("ac_ag_Id", [1,2,4,17], 'IN')->get("tbl_accounts")

Comment: @Gopal I have tried but did not worked for me.

Comment: can you show the Table values?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks a lot. This query worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `IN` clause instead of write multiple `OR` operator

```
SELECT  * FROM tbl_accounts WHERE  ac_ag_Id IN(1,2,4,17);
```

using `IN` clause you get all record which ac_ag_Id in (1,2,4,17).

for more about `IN clause` [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm). above query run on `mysql`. i am not php developer

Answer (score 1):

Like Vipin Jain suggested, you can use `IN` instead of many similar `OR`s. The syntax for MysqliDb Class would be:

```
$fromquery = $jdb->where("c_Id",$cc_Id)
                 ->where("ac_ag_Id", [1,2,4,17], 'IN')
                 ->get("tbl_accounts");
```